# Image preservation of Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, analytic-geometry

This might sound quite trivial. Let $\mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix}x_1,\ldots,x_N \end{pmatrix}^\top$ which takes on values on the $N$-dimensional orthant $\mathcal{O}_N = [0,\infty)^N$. If $\mathbf{y}$ is linear transformation of $\mathbf{x}$ defined as $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$ where $\mathbf{A}$ is an $N\times N$ transformation matrix (i.e., invertible),

$\mathbf{1.}$ is the image still $\mathcal{O}_N$?

$\mathbf{2.}$ If no, is there a necessary and sufficient condition in $\mathbf{A}$ for the the image to be preserved?

*Context:* Currently working on multivariate integration involving change-of-variables resulting to change in domain of integration.

Answer (score 3):

No, in general the image is not $\mathcal{O}_N$. This is easy to see, for example take $N=2$ and $A$ to be the standard rotation matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    cos\theta & -sin\theta \\
    sin\theta & cos\theta \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Here, if you put $\theta = 90^{\circ}$, then the image is completely disjoint from $\mathcal{O}_N$. Or you can use the shear matrix to obtain situations where the image is strictly contained in $\mathcal{O}_N$ or will strictly contain $\mathcal{O}_N$.

For your second question, it is easy to detect if the image is contained in $\mathcal{O}_N$. To check that, we just need to check if all the basis vectors of $\mathcal{O}_N$ land in $\mathcal{O}_N$.

To check if the image is exactly $\mathcal{O}_N$, we'll have to check whether every element of $\mathcal{O}_N$ (or at least the basis) has a preimage which will be no different than looking at the image of $\mathcal{O}_N$ and comparing.

Comment: This is quite insightful. Mind if I ask, what would happen if $\mathbf{A}$ is positive definite? Would it suffice for preservation of image?

Comment: I mean $\mathcal{O}_N$ where I accidentally wrote $\mathcal{0}_N$ in my previous comment.

Comment: Can you formalize the proof when you say "If $\mathbf{A}$ is positive definite, then image will be contained in $\mathcal{O}_N$" ?

Comment: Oh, I apologize. That statement isn't true. Example, you can take A to be the rotation matrix as in my answer with $0^{\circ} < \theta < 90^{\circ}$, and it will be positive definite. But the image won't lie in $\mathcal{O}_N$. I'm sorry for creating a misunderstanding. I'll remove my previous, extremely inaccurate comment now.

Comment: It's okay. I think I have the solution now. Your answer gave me an idea by considering eigendecomposition of $\mathbf{A}$.